# How to load page specific JS files with RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a multiple page website using RequireJS, which loads a boot strap file (boot.js), which then requires app.js.

app.js handles all the logic, and all other module initialization happens through app.initModule() (which is just a require() call wrapper)

I also have a app.loadPageJS() to load page specific JS files (based on window.location.pathname, for example, www.domain.com/path/to/file.html would auto-load /_assets/js/pages/path/to/file.js)

This feature can be turned on/off, and overridden by adding a class of "no-auto-load" or "auto-load" to the body, respectively.

Now, my approach isn't robust enough. For one, url rewriting would break the mechanism, and for two, if loadPageJS is turned off, unless I have access to the body tag, I can't include a page specific JS file (in the case of sites using templating systems, adding a class to the body tag isn't always an option).

What are other ways to include page specific code? I'd rather avoid the following:

- adding page specific code to a global.js file and doing if checks and only running certain code sets
- using a pageName variable (which would essentially be similar to the above)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different modules on the page sectioned by unique ID's (a newsletter module wrapped within a div with an ID of 'newsletter', etc), you could test for existence of the module element in the DOM and conditionally load in the JS file necessary to run that module. So rather than being page-specific, it is module specific.

Comment: I already do that. I was looking to group code that's not necessarily tied to modules, but to the page (some initialization code, or one off JS functionality that doesn't need to be modularized)